# Display last captured photo in a imageView? (Camera)

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

So actually I have an application, where you can take a photo about yourself, and then it's saves the photo inside the phone, in a created folder called MyCameraApp.

I want to show the last captured photo from my MyCameraApp folder to an imageview in my activity.

I have no idea how to do this, every tutorial or example i founded is looks really complicated for me, after 3-4 hour of search I think it's better to ask this community, hope someone can help to me :)

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");


        return mediaFile;
    }
```

I know it's sound dumb, but I want something like this:

```
Get last created mediafile
imageView.setBitmap(lastCreatedMediaFile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process might be the following:

- Capture picture (you have it)
- Save it to storage (you have it)
- Load `Bitmap` from storage
- Use `setImageBitmap()`

Loading from storage is achieved by using by `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(*)` for example on the same file object (`pictureFile` in your case)

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile);
        ImageView im3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        im3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Well actually i don't know what am I doing wrong but with this code I get  "decodeFile (java.lang.String)  in BitmapFactory cannot be applied to (java.io.file)" Error.

Comment: Use pictureFile.getAbsolutePath() to get path as String. And be sure to boost your Java knowledge a little bit ;)